# IOS - white font with black border?

Tags: ios, border, uifont

How have white font with black border?

without use his own font! is it possible?

like here -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohPQZ.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be achieved by `Quartz 2D`. You can take a look at this [Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007531) given by Apple. You can read the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_text/dq_text.html) also.

**Select the font :**

```
UIFont *font =  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0,0);
```

**Get the current Context :**

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

**Set Fill Color and Stroke Color :**

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
```

**Set Text Drawing Mode :**

```
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);
```

**Save State :**

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
[@"White Font With Black Border?" drawAtPoint:point withFont:font];
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```